# Wrapping Functions in Try-Catch Block in Javascript

Tags: javascript, try-catch

Is it possible to wrap functions inside a try-catch block?  It appears to not work for the first function, but would it work for the prototype function declared that way?

Example:

```
try {

    function MyFunction1() {

      //function code here

    }

    MyFunction1.prototype.getValue = function() {

      //more code here

   }

} catch (e) {

    //error handling here

}
```

Comment: apparently not, I've tested a script and it doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible to catch an exception in that way.

A try/catch block around a function **definition** does not catch exceptions thrown from that function.

You need a try/catch block either inside your function, or around the code that's actually calling the function instead.