# check if variables are undefined

Tags: javascript, function, undefined-reference

Is it possible to have a function that checks if any of arguments provided to it is undefined? I am trying out the following

```
function isDefined() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        if (typeof (arguments[i]) === "undefined") return false;
    return true;
}
```

However, It gives me an error if I pass an undefined argument:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: b is not defined

**Update**

Sample usage:

```
let a = 5;
let c = "hello";

isDefined(a, b, c); // gives false
isDefined(a, c); // gives true
```

Comment: Arguments are evaluated *before* the function is called. The function can't go back in time and prevent this error.

Comment: do if(!arguments[i]) return false

Comment: @ManosKounelakis How does that help? It just converts the argument to a boolean

Comment: you could write it like this `let isDefined = function(){ return [...arguments].some(arg=>!arg)}`

Comment: This error only occurs if the function is not *declared*. If you declare the variable you shouldn't get an error.

Comment: Why not wrapping your function inside another one that check the argument before calling the child function ?

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif Won't you just get the same error when calling the wrapper function?

Comment: @Barmar I edited my comment

Comment: @Barmar I am not sur I didnt try it before

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif, it's unlikely that it's possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17559576/5517100

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see it working is if you wrap isDefined in a try/catch. Your example usage would have to be modified as follows:

```
let a = 5;
let c = "hello";

try{
  isDefined(a, b, c); // gives false
}catch(e){
  // ... some code that can return false
}
try{
  isDefined(a, c); // gives true
}catch(e){
  // ... some code
}
```

Here's a working example:

```js
let a = 5;
// b isn't a thing 
let c = 'hello';
let d = null;
let e;


function isDefined() {
 !arguments;
 for (arg in arguments) {
  if(arguments[arg] === null || arguments[arg] === undefined) {
    return false;
  }
 }
 return true;
}


console.log(`isDefined(a, c): Result: ${isDefined(a, c)}`);
//you'd have to wrap isDefined in a try/catch if you're checking for this
try{
  console.log(`try{isDefined(a, b, c)}catch(e){...}: Result: ${isDefined(a, b, c)}`);
}catch(err){
  console.log('try{isDefined(a, b, c)}catch(e){...}: Result: false');
}

console.log(`isDefined(d) Result: ${isDefined(d)}`);
console.log(`isDefined(e): Result: ${isDefined(e)}`);
```

Comment: but this only works as far as you have defined b as `b = undefined`. this doesn't check in case b was never assigned

Comment: i meant without even the let d

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to run isDefined in a try catch.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isDefined() {
    return !Array.from(arguments).includes(undefined);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

undefined has the value null.
Any undefined elements in an array return null.

```
function isDefined() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        if (arguments[i]==null) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This wont slove the op issue

Comment: undefined and null are two different things.  As proof you can do `undefined === null` and you will see it is false.

Comment: === is different from ==, `undefined === null` returns false, and `undefined == null` returns true. Triple equal is more strict.